# Cannot access apache via external URL, only via remote desktop connection to server

Tags: apache, iis, xampp

I have a Windows 2012 Server via VPS hosting.

I installed IIS and MySQL last week.

I have no way to remotely access the MySQL db, so thought I'd try to set things up so that I can access it remotely.

I have installed XAMPP this evening, and installed Apache and PHP onto the server.

My domain name. e.g. mysite.com is linked to the VPS hosting, so that I can go to e.g. localhost/index.html and also mysite.com/index.html and see the same page.

I had to configure apache so that I could connect to it at the same time as running IIS, so access it via localhost:8080/phpMyAdmin/index.php. When connected via remote desktop connection, I can also access that via mysite.com:8080/phpMyAdmin/index.php.

However, if I disconnect the remote desktop connection and try again to get to mysite.com:8080/phpMyAdmin/index.php I get a timeout error.

I seem to only be able to access that URL when on the actual server that the site runs from, even though I can use the full external URL.

I wondered if there any way around this?

Comment: Did you add the host to your hosts file?

Comment: No sorry, I didn't. I have edited it now and added e.g.  (I'm making up my server IP for entering here) 132.23.32.12       mysite.com but it hasn't made any difference. On the hosts file there is a comment saying localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself, so presumably I can't map localhost to mysite.com? Sorry for asking stupid questions, I'm new to VPS hosting, I've only ever used shared hosting before

Comment: Can you try to add the port as well, like so 132.23.32.12 mysite.com:8080. 8080 is not the default http port, maybe that'll help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've given that a go, but unfortunately it hasn't done the trick.

Comment: In the end I contacted the hosting company who said the issue was due to the Windows Firewall blocking access to port 8080. After they added a rule to allow access, problem fixed.

Comment: Nice to hear that you finally got this working. So you actually did not do anything wrong. We just always have to keep firewalls in mind. :-) Have fun!